# \r is supposed to be a string but instead it is highlighted as something else

Tags: python

I get this error "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'ch16_downloading_data\data\readable_eq_data.json'"  In my readable_file line the "\r" of the word \readerable_eq_data is highlighted as something else even though it is wrapped with quotation marks to make it a string. Why is it like that?

```
import json

filename = "ch16_downloading_data\data\eq_data_1_day_m1.json"
with open(filename) as f:
    all_eq_data = json.load(f)

readable_file = "ch16_downloading_data\data\readable_eq_data.json"
with open(readable_file, "w") as f:
    json.dump(all_eq_data, f, indent=4)
```

Comment: single backslashes followed immediately by certain characters are interpreted as "control characters". backslash + r is an older Mac line ending control character, i believe. you can either do raw strings e.g. r"your string here", or forward slashes work even on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\r and \n are escape sequences for different kinds of newlines. Your input string is being mutated into

```
ch16_downloading_data\data
eadable_eq_data.json
```

For safety, escape your `\` in strings by using `\\` instead:

```
readable_file = "ch16_downloading_data\\data\\readable_eq_data.json"
```

While the \d is innocent, doing this'll give some peace of mind that you won't get tripped up by a return sequence you haven't heard of and protects against the slim chances of future ones being added to python.

Comment: Another way to approach this is to use `os.path.join()` with the path elements as its argument, so that you generate the filename to open in a safe and system-independent fashion.